# Как построить график по формуле?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, графика

Есть формула:

[image: Формула1]

R - скорость воспроизведения популяции в отсутствии внутривидовой конкуренции (математически это соответствует случаю a = 0).

Тогда уравнение определяет просто изменение численности популяции по закону геометрической прогрессии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где N0 - начальная численность популяции.

Также даны значения a = 5, b = 8, N0 = 200 в зависимости от значения параметра R в диапазоне 1 ≤ R ≤ 5

Пока что есть такой код:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  a = 5;
  b = 8;
  R = 2;
var
  x0,y0: Integer;
  x,y: Real;
begin
  // находим центр
  x0 := Image1.Width div 2;
  y0 := Image1.Height div 2;
  // рисуем оси
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(x0, 0);
  Image1.Canvas.LineTo(x0, ClientHeight);
  Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(0, y0);
  Image1.Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, y0);

  // рисуем график
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;

  // ... что делать здесь?

end;
```

Как дальше делать - я не знаю. Если подскажите на `TChart`, то также подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете функция которая принимает наборы входных параметров и возвращает результат в виде набора значений, который подставляется в `TChart`.

**Upd:**

Для подсчета значений формула будет выглядеть как то так:

Если у нас используется массив для хранения данных, тогда можно записать так (сперва осуществив инициализацию массива `SetLength(...)`), и сам подсчет:

```
for i:= 0 to t-1 do
  N[t+1] := (N[t]*R)/(1+ Power((a*N[t]),b));
```

> // ... что делать здесь?

нужно пройтись по полученному массиву N и нарисовать график, примерно так:

```
Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
for i:=0 to Length(N)-1 do
  Image1.Canvas.LineTo(i, N[i]);
```